# How do I Save phone Contacts to my own database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I am working on Contact base application in android platform, I want to write or save all the data of CONTACT phone app to my own Sqlite-database so i can add additional functionality,

Here is my source code:

```
package com.webpreneur_contactlist;



    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

        public class WebpreneurActivity extends ListActivity {

            private static final int CONTACT_CREATE = 0;
            private static final int CONTACT_EDIT = 1;
         public static  long id1;
            //select the second one, Android view menu
            private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
            private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

            private DBHandler dbHelper;
            private Cursor c;
            ImageButton imageButton;
             public static long  rowId;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                Log.d("database1" ,"0");
                Log.d("Your Location4", "ok4:");
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                Log.d("database1" ,"1");
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_webpreneur);
                Log.d("database1" ,"2");
                dbHelper = new DBHandler(this);
                Log.d("database1" ,"3");
                dbHelper.open();
                fillData();
                //dbHelper.open();

                //addListenerOnButton();
            //dbHelper.addContact();

            imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
            Log.d("database1" ,"button");
            imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Log.d("database1" ,"b4");
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContactEdit.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i, CONTACT_CREATE);

                    Log.d("database1" ,"button3");
                    //fillData();

                }

            });

            //dbHelper.close();
        }








        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void fillData() {
            Log.d("Your Location4", "ok6:");
            c = dbHelper.fetchAllRows();
            Log.d("Your Location4", "ok8:");
            //startManagingCursor(c);
            Log.d("Your Location4", "ok2:");
             NoIdCursorWrapper nc = new NoIdCursorWrapper(c, DBHandler.Key_ID);
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.contact_row, nc, new String[] { DBHandler.Key_Name,
                            DBHandler.Key_Phone }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                            R.id.phonenumber });
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }




            protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position,   long id) {
                super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

                Intent i = new Intent(this, ContactEdit.class);
                i.putExtra(DBHandler.Key_ID, c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(DBHandler.Key_ID)));
                i.putExtra(DBHandler.Key_Name, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBHandler.Key_Name)));
                i.putExtra(DBHandler.Key_Address, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBHandler.Key_Address)));
                i.putExtra(DBHandler.Key_Phone, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBHandler.Key_Phone)));
                i.putExtra(DBHandler.Key_Website, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBHandler.Key_Home)));
                startActivityForResult(i, CONTACT_EDIT);
        }
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                    Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    String name = data.getStringExtra(DBHandler.Key_Name);
                    String address = data.getStringExtra(DBHandler.Key_Address);
                    String mobile = data.getStringExtra(DBHandler.Key_Phone);
                    String home = data.getStringExtra(DBHandler.Key_Home);
                    //String id = data.getStringExtra(DBHandler.Key_ID);
                    switch (requestCode) {
                    case CONTACT_CREATE:
                        Log.d("Your Location4", "jj:");
                        dbHelper.createRow(name, address, mobile, home);
                    Log.d("Your Location4"  , "ok90:");
                        fillData();
                        break;
                    case CONTACT_EDIT:

                        //String id = data.getStringExtra(DBHandler.Key_ID);
                        //long rowId=Long.parseLong(DBHandler.Key_ID); ////Giving null pointer exception at this point
                        long rowId=data.getLongExtra(DBHandler.Key_ID, 0);
                         Log.d("Your Location4" , "ok9b:");
                        if (rowId != 0){
                            dbHelper.updateRow(rowId, name, address, mobile, home);
                        }
                        fillData();
                        break;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class level:

```
Uri uri;
String[] projection;
String where;
String[] selectionArgs;
```

onCreate: (Note clause exists for records with birthdays)

```
uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI; // Set the URI for Query of Contacts database

    //==================================================================
    //Projection String Array (Fields we are interested in capturing) 
    //==================================================================
    projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
    };


    //==================================================================
    //Where Clause for the Database Query
    //==================================================================
    where = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "= ? AND "
            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE + "="
            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY;




    // Easy? Selection args
    selectionArgs = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };



getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this); //Loader init
```

outside onCreate:

```
@Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {

        CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(this, uri, projection, where,
                selectionArgs, null);
        return loader;
    }

    //  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        Map<String, List<String>> BD = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        if(cursor !=null){
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();


                contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTACT_ID));
                li.add(contactId);


                String displayBirthday = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE));
                //==================================================================
                // Handle the curious case of Date without Year
                //==================================================================
                if(displayBirthday.length()<8){
                    displayBirthday = displayBirthday.replace("--", "0001-"); 
                }
                //==================================================================
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                li.add(displayBirthday);


                Uri phUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,String.valueOf(contactId));



                String Ur = String.valueOf(phUri);


                li.add(Ur);
                String DateStr = displayBirthday;
                Date d = null;
                try {
                    d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"/*, current*/).parse(DateStr);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                java.sql.Date d1 = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());

                BD.put(name, li);
                li = null;

            }
```

BD is your Hashmap with records, write it to the DB.

Comment: BUt question is how do i add these detail to my own dAtabase "DBHANDLER",

Comment: Get the individual elements from the HashMap and write? Also remember Maps have a unique key, over writing which means losing previous key-data. You can skip the adding into the map and instead directly insert values as soon as you get em!

Comment: sorry nun i am not geeting your since i am beginner please help me out

Comment: Check the onLoadFinished function, inside the while loop you get all values, now you need to add them accordingly to your DB

Comment: what if i want to get photo of contact, and gmail contact as well as phone contact?

Comment: The picture part is covered above, there are various methods for the same and you must check the official docs for the same. Check this: http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/1/

Comment: so do i add xml files for getting photos to my own database, and plz tell me how can i then show this data to my own app e.g listview,, i just want to show like a native Android contacts show these data on there app,

Comment: You dont have to use an XML file, just get the image URI and save it, then retrieve the image from the URi. Saving images in DB is costly also you will have to implement a custom Cursor adapter in your list so that view recycling is taken care of, otherwise you will get duplicates in your list. It is a complete project I can only show you the door, its you who has to walk through!

Comment: ok thanku so much sir I appreciate

Comment: but nun one last thing in this project i never seen it saves contacts to custom database? will you please guide in this regard

Comment: The process is two steps, you get the values first(From the contacts DB). Second, you add these values to the DB(Your own DB).

Comment: but how can i show these values after adding to my database

Comment: Once you add these values to the DB you will have to implement a query, get the results in a cursor, create a custom cursor adapter which will back your list and iterate through the cursor data, display them in the list. You will get an idea here: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296 and here:http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.in/2013/09/android-populate-listview-from-sqlite.html

Comment: Ok Nun thank you much for your help really worth it!